# Make td elements of an HTML table a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I have a pandas dataframe that I am using to generate an HTML table (`dataframe.to_html()`).  I want to make one of the columns of the table a dropdown menu with two options that will allow the user to specify *Accept* or *Reject* for that row of the table, but I am having trouble figuring out the best way to go about this.

*Python code*:

```
df = random_pandas_dataframe
pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth',-1)

html_table = re.sub(' task_table', '" id="task_table', df.to_html(classes='task_table'))
```

This html table is given to my Django template, which is then displayed like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  {{ html_table | safe }}
</div>
```

Does anyone know how best to edit the html table so that one of the columns is a dropdown menu with *Accept* and *Reject* options?  I'm fine using javascript to do it if possible.

Comment: Do you mean HTMLTableElement, or are you building a table using divs?

Comment: @Teemu the top level is a div that contains the table.  But `dataframe.to_html()` (which creates `html_table`) produces html table elements.  So I would want to turn all of the `<td>` elements in one column into a dropdown menu.

Comment: I'd suggest to use bootstrap since it already handle's [dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) you just have to use their convention of tags and classes.

Comment: @Teemu why would that cause a problem?

Comment: @multivac how would you add the `ul` elements to an existing `td` element?

Comment: @kdubs does each row need to have a dropdown? you'd need to put the toggle button + ul menu inside the td, like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/RPjYWUFlxDR2GmXWlQf3?p=preview)

Comment: @multivac yes each row needs to have a dropdown but it's the same column and the same dropdown for each row.

Comment: @multivac I was able to adapt the code that you gave in your plunker example to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr >
<td class = "select">
    <select>
        <option value ="accept">Accept</option>
        <option value ="reject">Reject</option>

    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).